# Does AWS Route 53 private DNS work with Latency Based Routing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-dns, amazon-route53

Looking to setup a private DNS hosted zone in AWS Route 53. I would like to know if this configuration supports Latency Based Routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-latency.html):

> Although creating latency records in a private hosted zone is allowed, it's not supported.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported now. Please see the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/amazon-route-53-launches-geolocation-latency-based-routing-private-dns/) from AWS.